# How to parse output data from ans matlab

Tags: matlab, parsing, output

I wonder how to parse standart output for using it further?

For example, I'm solving a LP problem:

```
f = [-7 -5];
A = [2 3; 3 1; 0 3; 3 0];
b = [25 20 18 15];
point = linprog(f,A,b)
```

I've got

```
point =

    5.0000
    5.0000
```

But then I want to use it in

```
text(point, '\leftarrow Optimal')
```

And Matlab shows

```
Error using text
Not enough input arguments.
```

I understand why: because *text* whants something like this: `text(5,5,'\leftarrow Optimal')`... 
So how can I parse my point output to make my text work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
text(point(1),point(2), '\leftarrow Optimal')
```

**edit**

To add together strings here are a few different ways of doing it:

```
str=num2str(optvalue,'%s')
text(point(1),point(2), ['\leftarrow Optimal' str])
% or
text(point(1),point(2), strcat ( '\leftarrow Optimal', str ) )
% or
text(point(1),point(2), sprintf ( '\\leftarrow Optimal %s', str ) )
```

Look up the matlab help on each topic to understand how to use them.

Comment: Yes! Thanx a lot! Now I know that to specify line in standart output you should just add (i)!

Comment: And if I want to add `optvalue = -f * point` and add the result to the _text_ line? Something like `str=num2str(optvalue,'%s');text(point(1),point(2), '\leftarrow Optimal:str')` doesn't work =(

Comment: Thats works fine! I've added a precision `str=num2str(optvalue,'%6.2f');` and thats what I all wanted. Thanks again!